# Noun for receiving end of promotion?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

When promoting someone or something to a higher standing, is there a noun that can be used to describe the object of the promotion? Something equivalent to "the guy being promoted" is basically what I'm looking for. My first thought is "promotee" but that just strikes me as odd/wrong for some reason.

Comment: Which dictionaries did you consult? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promotee

Comment: Dictionaries are some of the worst ways to figure out what words can and can't be used in writing or conversation.

Comment: I don't much like "promotee", but [here](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=promotee&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) are over 2000 written instances, so one can hardly say it's "wrong" to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would the term **recipient** work?

Comment: Much better fit, works excellently and sounds better in the context

Answer (score 1):

The form I would use is promot**ed**.

He just got promoted. or
He is a newly promoted person.